# No space on /boot

Tags: boot, lubuntu, disk-usage

I get an error message each time I use the Software Updater in Lubuntu 16.04, saying I don't have enough space on `/boot`. I would need 94 MB free space, which I apparently haven't got:

```
$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       236M  156M   68M  70% /boot

$ ls -l
total 150379
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1240018 jun 24  2016 abi-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1240067 jul 13  2016 abi-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1245659 mar 31 19:14 abi-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   189533 jun 24  2016 config-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   189558 jul 13  2016 config-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190236 mar 31 19:14 config-4.4.0-72-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 apr 19 11:53 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38404788 apr 18 17:11 initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38387763 apr 18 17:17 initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38941335 apr 19 11:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 feb 14  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3859655 jun 24  2016 System.map-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3866473 jul 13  2016 System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3882277 mar 31 19:14 System.map-4.4.0-72-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7026864 jun 24  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7047504 jul 13  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7083248 mar 31 19:14 vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
```

I have already done a `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Any ideas what else I should do or remove to be able to update?

Comment: What are the content of /boot/lost+found, if any ?

Comment: @SorenA There is nothing in the lost+found folder.

Comment: @Yaron I didn't reckon I have any old kernel images lying around (as I did the autoremove), so I didn't think the answers of that question helped in my case.

Comment: @Ingrid - the output of your `ls -l` shows 3 versions of linux kernel/initd/etc - please review again the answers in the link

Comment: @Yaron Right, sorry, I didn't realise they were kernels - thought they were actually supposed to be called "linux-image" :/ Will check the answers out again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your older kernels to start with.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
```

May aswell also remove headers while your at it.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.4.0-31
```

If you want even more space, remove kernel 4.4.0-28 as well, although it is usually good practice to have an older kernel installed in case you have issues with the latest one.

Moving forward, you can always increase the size of the /boot partition. (I don't bother with a seperate boot partition any more).